# Gulp streamqueue sass plumber watch. Errors breaks task

Tags: stream, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, plumber

Have a problem occurs with gulp task using the Streamqueue, sass, plumber and watching it at the end.
The Task is compiling production css-file from vendors css|scss files with my own.

```
gulp.task('fincss', function () {
    watch([workData.sassSrcFiles, workData.cssVendorSrcFiles], {}, function () {
        var convertFromScssToCssAndConcat =
            gulp.src(workData.sassSrcFiles)
                .pipe(plumber(error))
                .pipe(sass());

        var minifyAndConcatExistingCss =
            gulp.src(workData.cssVendorSrcFiles)
                .pipe(plumber(error));

        return sq({objectMode: true}, minifyAndConcatExistingCss, convertFromScssToCssAndConcat)
            .pipe(concat('final.min.css'))
            .pipe(uglifycss())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(workData.cssDest))
            .pipe(livereload());
    });
});

var error = function (e) {
    console.error('Error in plugin "' + e.plugin + '"');
    console.error('   "' + e.message + '"');
    console.error('   In file "' + e.fileName + '", line "' + e.lineNumber + '".');
    console.log('--------------------------------------');
    console.log(e);
};
```

But when error in scss file then breaking task. And any experiments with plumber which provides in Internet doesn't helps me anyway. Something like inserting plumber() before `concat`, or using `this.emit('end')` in the error handler do nothing.

In other my tasks like

```
gulp.task('toHtml', function () {
    watch(workData.pugSrcFiles, {}, function (e) {
        message('Start generating template.');
        gulp.src([workData.pugSrcFiles, '!' + workData.pugSrc + '_*.pug'])
            .pipe(plumber(error))
            .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(pubDir))
            .pipe(livereload());
    });
});
```

all works pretty good and without breaking task.

Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream-series to replace streamqueue.

change your config file to:

```
var series = require('stream-series');

gulp.task('fincss', function () {
    watch([workData.sassSrcFiles, workData.cssVendorSrcFiles], {}, function () {
        var convertFromScssToCssAndConcat =
            gulp.src(workData.sassSrcFiles)
                .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: function(error) {
                     convertFromScssToCssAndConcat.emit('end')  // important
                 }}))
                .pipe(sass());

        var minifyAndConcatExistingCss =
            gulp.src(workData.cssVendorSrcFiles)
                .pipe(plumber(error));

        return series(minifyAndConcatExistingCss, convertFromScssToCssAndConcat)
            .pipe(concat('final.min.css'))
            .pipe(uglifycss())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(workData.cssDest))
            .pipe(livereload());
    });
```

});

Comment: Hi, @leon 
thanks
But I get error `\node_modules\stream-series\index.js:23 e.pipe(pauseStream);
TypeError: e.pipe is not a function
at node_modules\stream-series\index.js:23:7
at Array.forEach (native)
at module.exports node_modules\stream-series\index.js:20:11)
at C:\projects\jp\gulpfile.js:83:16
at write (C:\projects\jp\node_modules\gulp-watch\index.js:144:3)
at node_modules\gulp-watch\node_modules\vinyl-file\index.js:52:4
at node_modules\gulp-watch\node_modules\vinyl-file\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)`

Comment: @PaulBurilichev, I can not know what happened from the error log you copied here. But `stream-series` should be able to work. I have used it in my project, you can refer to line 118 of https://github.com/njleonzhang/generator-gulp-ionic/blob/master/generators/app/templates/_gulpfile.js

Comment: @PaulBurilichev, sorry for the typo, 

`return series({objectMode: true}, minifyAndConcatExistingCss, convertFromScssToCssAndConcat) `
should be `
return series(minifyAndConcatExistingCss, convertFromScssToCssAndConcat)`